# inverter, air conditioning, electricity savings

Tags: electrical, air-conditioning, utilities, inverter

Having two AC units of the same BTU and EER, one inverter one non-inverter, is my understanding correct that the inverter unit will still run on less power than the non-inverter unit only due to less ON/OFF cycles alone ? If this is true I suppose it is also true for same COP instead of same EER. What sort of savings, %-wise, would there be based on just the inverter / non-inverter factor ?

And if there was a hard start kit installed into the non-inverter unit, will these savings become negligible ?

Comment: It depends on the amount of cooling required if you have a much larger system that would cycle if not on a vfd in that case the vfd or inverter would provide a large savings but if the systems were undersized to they ran 100 % the vfd won’t save much only at the start and end of the cooling season when it would cycle  but if running all the time no savings

Comment: @EdBeal That must be 'cooling session', not season.

Comment: Actually I meant season once the system starts regularly that is considered cooling season and the reason hvac tech time cost more, why they are in demand , folks don’t think about having systems serviced in the heating season normally only when they need it (and many calls come in) so getting on the schedule in cooling season costs more or a long wait. The same thing happens for heaters at the start of heating season.